# PyCharm - Docker / Jupyter server process finishedrunnerw.exe: CreateProcess failed with error 2: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: docker, pycharm, jupyter

[image]I have recently started using Jupyter via Pycharm/Docker remote integration. Whenever I want to run a cell, this started popping up and I can no longer use it. Any idea what could be the problem? Thanks.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the full error stacktrace in the body of the post.

Comment: The error is exactly what i wrote. In the log files, it is the same. Nothing else is written. I am suspicious of path mappings but cannot figure it out